# What is the meaning of grep on a Hash?

Tags: ruby

```
{'a' => 'b'}.grep /a/
=> []
>> {'a' => 'b'}.grep /b/
=> []
```

It doesn't seem to match the keys or values.  Does it do something I'm not discerning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`grep` is defined on `Enumerable`, i.e. it is a generic method that doesn't know anything about `Hash`es. It operates on whatever the elements of the `Enumerable` are. Ruby doesn't have a type for key-value-pairs, it simply represents `Hash` entries as two-element arrays where the first element is the key and the second element is the value.

`grep` uses the `===` method to filter out elements. And since neither

```
/a/ === ['a', 'b']
```

nor

```
/b/ === ['a', 'b']
```

are true, you always get an empty array as response.

Try this:

```
def (t = Object.new).===(other)
  true
end

{'a' => 'b'}.grep t
# => [['a', 'b']]
```

Here you can see how `grep` works with `Hash`es.

Comment: Thanks, I see that === is defined for Object, but not overridden for Hash, so it's not really meaningful.  But at least I see now that: {'a' => 'b'}.grep Array ... => [["a", "b"]]

Comment: @user258980: The fact that `Hash#===` is not defined is completely irrelevant, since you are not calling `Hash#===`, you are calling `Hash#grep`. `Hash#grep` then calls the `===` method of whatever object was passed into it. In your example, that object is `/a/`, so `Hash#grep` ends up calling `Regexp#===` passing each element in turn. Since those elements are two-element arrays, and a `Regexp` obviously never can match an array, only strings, the result will always be empty.